# CentOS, How to allow SSH through only one server-ip

Tags: centos, iptables, ip

I currently have a dedicated server with two pv4 IP addresses assigned to it. I want to make one public, and the other private for SSH/FTP related material.

IP 1 (The public ip): 192.23.6.11

IP 2 (The private SSH ip): 192.23.6.12

Anybody know how i'd BLOCK IP 1 from SSH/SFTP? Is it even possible?

Comment: You even tagged the question with `iptables`...

Comment: Because i assumed it was IPTable related rather then sshd_config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we make sure that ssh listens only to the desired ip.

In the following file:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

You'll see a line like:

```
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

This is commented out, but is the default, to list on all IP addresses for ssh requests. You can change this so that it is the IP address of the interface you want to accept connections on, and so only that IP address will accept ssh connections:

```
ListenAddress 192.23.6.12
```

Restart the sshd service once changed.

Then allow in iptables the interface with the private ip (eg eth1)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  -i eth1 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

See also:

- http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH
- http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables

Answer (score 1):

Add/edit the following line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

ListenAddress 192.23.6.12